# Java swt drag object into "dead space" to create a new window

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I'm looking to emulate window dragging with my software. I currently have canvases that act like its own window in a view. I've created a drag and drop between them and this works all very solid. However, I'm looking to do a drag case when I drag and drop out into dead space. Or better phrased as an area that isn't covered by my application. My first thought was to listen for the mouse to move outside of the current shell and then do something. However, I can not seem to find a way to detect that I'm outside of the shell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not seem to find a way to detect that I'm outside of the shell.

If you're using a [MouseListener](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMouseListener.html), you can implement the [mouseUp(MouseEvent)](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/MouseListener.html#mouseUp(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent)) method and get the point where the mouse was released via the [MouseEvent](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMouseListener.html&anchor=mouseUp(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent)) object.

```
@Override
public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent event) {
    final Point releasePoint = new Point(e.x, e.y);
}
```

Note that this position will be relative to the parent Shell of the object that this listener was added to. You'll need to add the location of that parent Shell to the (x,y) pair above to get the absolute position on the screen.

Now that you have the point at which the mouse was released after clicking some target object, you can check if that is outside of the original window using the [Rectangle.contains(Point)](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Rectangle.html#contains(org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point)) method.

```
final Composite target = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
target.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent event) {
        final Point releasePoint = new Point(event.x + target.getShell().getLocation().x,
                                             event.y + target.getShell().getLocation().y);
        if (!target.getShell().contains(releasePoint)) {
            // Dragged and dropped outside the window!
        }
    }
});
```

From here you can do whatever work you need to do to create a new shell and move the target over to that shell.

---

Here's a little working example I threw together where you can drag and drop a yellow rectangle out of one window and it will create a new window with the rectangle inside:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Original shell");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setMaximized(true);

    final Composite parentComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    parentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    parentComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Composite target = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
    target.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
    target.setBackground(new Color(display, 255, 255, 0));
    target.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent event) {
            final Point releasePoint = new Point(event.x + target.getShell().getLocation().x,
                                                 event.y + target.getShell().getLocation().y);
            if (!target.getShell().getBounds().contains(releasePoint)) {
                // Create the new shell and base composite
                final Shell newShell = new Shell(display);
                newShell.setText("New shell");
                newShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
                newShell.setMaximized(true);
                final Composite newComposite = new Composite(newShell, SWT.NONE);
                newComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
                newComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

                // Set the parent of the target widget to the new base composite
                target.setParent(newComposite);
                target.layout();

                // Open the new shell
                newShell.setLocation(releasePoint);
                newShell.setSize(300, 300);
                newShell.open();
            }
        }
    });

    shell.setSize(300, 300);
    shell.open();
    display.readAndDispatch();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch()) {
            shell.getDisplay().sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Just to clarify, if you use a Canvas (which you mention in your question) instead of a Composite for the `target` object, it will behave exactly the same.